# Prove an inequality with two sigma notations

Tags: inequality

I am stuck at this inequality question that I cannot solve.

The question writes: Given a list of numbers k0, k1, k2, ...,kn that k1+k2+...+kn=0, and k0=0 
Prove:

I find the (j-i) part extremely annoying. I really hope some kind souls may give me some guidance in solving this inequality. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Look at the right hand side. Isn't it always $0$, since the term for $i=a,j=b$ exactly cancels the term for $i=b,j=a$? Same with the second term on the left.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the absolute signs. Now the edited version should be correct.

Comment: The left side is equal to $4d^2n(n-1)$ using symmetry. The same argument can be applied to the second term, and thus the inequality can be simplified easily.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more? I understand that the rightmost term can be simplified, but how can I apply the same approach that you proposed to the second term? It seems that there will be k existing on the square and linear term of d.

Comment: For $n=3$, $d=1$, and $k_i=0$ for all $i$, the left hand side is $2$ and the right hand side is something bigger than $2$. Also, you mention $k_0=0$ but $k_0$ does not appear anywhere else in the problem, suggesting you've made a mistake in the problem statement.